# How does one backup a Fire HD's entire system as is (like a PC "image", and after having been modded with Fire Toolbox) and restore it?

Tags: backup, restore

My parents play slot machine games, but they continually lose their play money and require me to factory reset their tablets to reset the default amount of money. Clearly, this takes a while to do every time.

I would like to factory reset, mod with Fire Toolbox, setup all their games/apps/settings and then create a backup image of this setup, which I can then restore much faster than having do it all that setup again every time.

Is there a method for this? Amazon's cloud feature is not an option.

Comment: Instead of doing a factory reset, have you tried clearing their app data instead?

Comment: @AndrewT. Clearing app data/cache does not reset the money amounts. They are pay-real-money-to-win games and I'm guessing that the devs have imbedded their settings into the "root", which unrooted players cannot access. Maybe rooting/deleting files would work? I haven't tried, but there's no guides on the net.